# Enabling truncation in transformers feature extraction pipeline

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm using the transformers FeatureExtractionPipeline like this:

```
from transformers import pipeline, LongformerTokenizer, LongformerModel

tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')

model = LongformerModel.from_pretrained("allenai/longformer-base-4096")

nlu_feature_pipeline = pipeline(task="feature-extraction", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

However, it seems like the pipeline doesn't use truncation to ensure that no sequence is longer 4096, resulting in this:

> Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (8912 > 4096). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors

Is there any way I can enable the truncation in the pipeline? Or is it somehow possible to maybe tokenize beforehand and then feed it into the pipeline?

Comment: The "feature-extraction" pipeline does not support truncation because it would be contrary to its purpose. You have to truncate or split the input by yourself.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I understand "contrary to it's purpose"